# is it possible to make program aliases in `stack exec`?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a project that has many small executable targets. It takes quite a lot of time whenever the source code changes due to the problem that you cannot avoid building every executables in the project.

So instead I'm trying to have one single executable who decides its own behavior by checking its name (perhaps by using [`getProgName`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/System-Environment.html)): for example, I can build a single executable name `foo`, and two soft links targeting at it, one called `progA` and another `progB`: I want it to behave like there are three separated programs:

- `foo [progA|progB]` print help messages when arguments are missing, or run as if it's `progA` or `progB` if `foo` is equal to either of them
- `progA` & `progB`: as if there are separated binaries

As I don't want my project executables to be exposed globally, what I usually do is just `stack build && stack exec -- <progName> [...args]`. My question is: is it possible to have one single executable (namely `foo` in my example) in `.cabal` file, while stack does something under the hood to make available `stack exec -- progA` and `stack exec -- progB`?

I know I could get and parse `PATH` from the environment in which `stack exec` runs, and make soft links accordingly there, but I'll prefer a less hacky method.

Comment: The usual solution is to make the executables separate projects that depend on a shared library.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs that's actually what I'm currently doing, but there are many executables in my project, even linking each of them takes sometime and I cannot choose to link only some of them due to [stack#issue1406](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1406)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have k `executable` fields in your cabal file which you would like to replace with a single executable field, but still have `stack exec` recognize the k executables you have before. I don't think that is possible, but I think you could have k `executable` fields as before, except replacing `k-1` of them with some 'dummy' program (e.g. `main = return ()`) and having a custom `Setup.hs` which has a hook which overwrites the dummies with the 'true' executable. This still requires many `executable` fields, but it doesn't require linking the same program many times.

Comment: Or you could use git's (conceptual) model: one executable with k subcommands.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs that's the idea I initially came up with, i.e. `foo` in my example, but later I want to shorten the commands a bit, therefore turning `foo progA ...` into `progA ...`

Comment: @user2407038 yes that's what I'm trying to do. I've been considering `Setup.hs` to be a project boilerplate for years, but in my case this might come in handy - I'll take a look and see if that works